# Creating a "polite" scroll snap in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a "polite" scroll snap. You might be familiar with <strike>parallax</strike> scrolling which will sometimes locks panels into the window of the browser - this makes it feel you are fighting with the scroll bar. Apple's website used to use it. Here is a [good example](http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/).

What I want to do is do some detection on the mouse movement - so if the mouse hasn't moved 3 seconds then the scroll will move the to correct location. I have found some short snippets of jQuery but I'm struggling to piece it together so that it works. As I'm trying to learn and this is a bit of a challenge I just need someone to set me off in the right direction...

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxzk4/594/)

```
var timeout = null;

$(window).on('mousemove', function() {

$(function(){
var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
var individualDivHeight = 300;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var totalHeight = $('#container').height();
    var posToScroll = Math.round(_cur_top / individualDivHeight) *    individualDivHeight;
}); 
});


if (timeout !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: posToScroll}, 200);
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I agree, that scroll snap is not great UX. By the way, I think you might have the idea of parallax wrong. Parallax is a 2d representation of a 3d scenario in which the background elements move slower than the foreground elements. A good example is this website http://melanie-f.com/en/

Comment: Just to let you know, this is implemented in plugins such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) as you can see [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html). Although in this case sections are scrolled automatically unless you use the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxzk4/599/). When you mouse move, the counter restarts.

EDIT:

If you stay idle for 3 seconds then the page will either scroll to the top of the current box or to the end of the current box depending on the value of the threshold and the scrollTop value (0.5 means halfway between a block). Hope this helps.

```
var timeout = null;
var threshold=0.5;
$(window).on('mousemove', function() {
    if(timeout)clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(function(){
        var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.box').each(function(){
            var $this=$(this);
            var boxHeight = this.offsetHeight;
            var boxTop=this.offsetTop;
            if(_top<boxTop)return;
            if(_top<boxTop+(boxHeight*threshold)) {
                // Go back to the top of the current block
                $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: boxTop}, 200);
            }
            else {
                // Go forward to the end of the current block
                $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: boxTop+boxHeight}, 200);
            }
        });
},3000);
```

});

Comment: Thanks @Jackson - I guess that answers my question - and you are right about the Parallax definition.

How would we change this so that it scrolls to the panel with the majority of screen(share). That would mean it might have to scroll down to the bottom of a panel instead of to the top as it currently does. This woulds make it more intelligent and subtle (overall increasing it's ux manners). A [great example](http://tinyurl.com/mb7nxk3)